# Override findAll() Spring Data Gemfire Repo Queries

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-gemfire

I have millions of objects populated in GemFire regions. I don't want default `findAll()` SDR query to be executed to retrieve the millions of objects in one shot. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to override the default findAll query and provide the LIMIT param to restrict the number of objects retrieved from GemFire Regions. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

/**
 * Returns all instances of the type.
 * 
 * @return all entities
 */
Iterable<T> findAll();
}


public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyRepoObject, String> {


@Query("SELECT * FROM MyRegion LIMIT $1")
Iterable<CellTower> findAll(@Param("limit") String limit);

}
```

Currently, I am on Spring Data Gemfire 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and Spring Data REST 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version

Answer (score 0):

This handy getting started guide on Accessing GemFire Data with REST (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-gemfire-data-rest/) was written not long ago and may help with your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.  Try using an Integer instead of a String as your parameter to findAll

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM /Customer LIMIT $1")
    List<Customer> findAll(@Param("limit") Integer max);
```